# Windows Security essentials detected trojan in Hp Factory.wim

Tags: virus, ms-security-essentials, trojan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Security essential detected trojan:wind32/Anomaly.gen!A in containerfile: E:\system.sav\util\HPDactory.wim
file:E:\system.sav\util\HPFactory.wim->(Image76999)\Program Files (x86)\HP Games\Plants vs. Zombies\Plants vs. Zombies-WT.exe->(EXEEmb)->(EXEEmb)->(EXEEmb)->(EXEEmb)->(EXEEmb)->(EXEEmb)->(EXEEmb)->(EXEEmb)

Security essential report error of cant remove or quarantine. What should I do?

Comment: As explained by Dustin G, this is Not an infection and should Not be closed. A false positive and should not be removed as it will damage the HP restore wim file, possible causing HP restore to fail if it is ever used from the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I have seen products such as Norton, Webroot, AVG, and Security Essentials detect items on the recovery partition or other pre-loaded applications as a virus and or malware.

It appears that in your case, Security Essentials specifically picked up Wild Tangent from the  HP factory image (.wim = Windows Imaging Format) as an infection. While Wild Tangent (a gaming platform) is not a virus, many products consider it spywayre.

In this case, you should be fine, but it's always important to keep an eye on these things.